# Подогнать изображение под размер блока

Tags: css

Имеется что-то типа:

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="" class="">
</div>
```

Как сделать, что `img-container` всегда был 1x1 и при этом картинка в контейнере всегда была ровно по центру (горизонтально и вертикально)?

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы сохранять пропорции 1:1 понадобиться родительский container.
А позиционировние картинки осуществляется абсолютно с auto-отступами и заданием максимальных размеров:

```css
.container { 
  margin: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: calc(100% - 2 * 4px); /* отнимаем удвоеный размер рамки */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px solid red; 
}

.img-container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200">
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
  </div>
</div>
```